# pass previous promise result to bluebird join

Tags: promise, bluebird

Can I pass previous result to `using()` function? like this:

```
Promise.resolve([dbcfg])
    .then(getConnection())
    .using(runSql1, runSql2, runSql3)
```

From offical api document and examples, I just can find `Promise.using()` or `Promise.join()` but seems there is no way to passing privious result to the concurrency jobs?

------------------- edit -------------------

My purpose is connect to db then run 3 concurrecy sqls (they dun depends on each other), hmmm, should I use `.all()` instead of?

Comment: `using` is for resource management, I don't think your code does what you think it does - also - you're _calling_ getConnection outside the promise chain which passes _a promise_ to the `then` which is ignored (vs a function).

Comment: thanks. Yes, `.using()` is for resource management, may be the `.all()` is correct function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is like:

```
using(getConnection(configuration), function(conn) {
    return Promise.all([runSql1(conn), runSql2(conn), runSq3(conn)]);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my purpose is run sqls concurrency, they are not depends on any other one (actually they are `select` statements, so no worries). thanks anyway.

Comment: @jovi ah I see, I updated the answer. `.all` is indeed what you want in that case